# Categorical variables are not properly summarized when running the summary() function on Data Frame

Tags: r, dataframe, summary, factors

```r
df <- read.csv("student-mat.csv", sep = ";")

head(df)
```

[The Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PJlNG.png)

Now when I run `summary(df)`

[Expected Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MmMWx.jpg)

[My Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rXx4t.png)

Why don't I get the proper descriptive summary for categorical variables / factors (e.g. A count for the two genders under the "sex" factor).

Background Information:

Operating System: macOS High Sierra Version 10.13.6

RStudio Version 1.3.959

Comment: Check `?as.factor`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define your variables as a factor. E.g `df$sex <- as.factor(df$sex)`

Let me know if it worked :)

Comment: Yes, I redefined each character columns in the same way that you showed and it works, thank you! Do you know an efficient way of redefining all character classes in my column as factors at once, instead of one by one?

Comment: Glad I could help :)